# How do I keep a Jenkins cron job from starting again until the triggered job is completed?

Tags: python, jenkins, cron

I have a Jenkins pipeline on an cron 1 minute timer that runs a python script.The python script checks a server for changes in flags for files and if it sees the flag on a file, it downloads it. Most of the time there are no changes but when there is it can take 5+ minutes to download the newly marked file. During that time Jenkins will continue to run on the cron timer while the file download is still going on and the triggered jenkins job is still running. How can I tell jenkins to ignore starting the next cron triggered job until the download  job is complete?

Comment: You can write a small groovy method to check the status of the job if it is running simple ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

A groovy method like below

```
   def getJobStatus(String jobName){
    def jenkins = Jenkins.getInstance()
    def job = Hudson.instance.getJob(jobName)
    return "${job.getLastBuild().building}"
    }

 def status = getJobStatus("jobName")
 if(status){
 echo "last job is running..."
 exit 0
 }
 else {
 echo "run something..."
 }
```